# Tunnel diodes Zener breakdown

Tags: diodes, zener

Do tunnel diodes exhibit Zener breakdown? Since tunnel diodes are more doped than Zener diodes they should, but I am unsure.

Comment: Ask yourself - are you running a tunnel diode with a reverse bias? Then go onto google and see why that question is important for zener breakdown.

Comment: I guess not current gets too high.

Comment: They'll certainly have a breakdown voltage, and probably not an impressive one.  I wouldn't *purposely* operate one there, because I know that (A) a bog-standard 2N2222 or 2N3904 has a pretty reliable 6V zener breakdown in it's base-emitter junction, and (B) the standard advice from amateur radio circuit designers is that once you've pulled one out of your junkbox and used it as a zener, you shouldn't use it as a transistor any more.

Comment: They seem to conduct Ip (~1mA) at at few tens of mV reverse voltage.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany aren't those the backward diodes?

Comment: Ge diodes 1N3712-1N3715

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical IV curve of a tunnel diode shows that the breakdown voltage is positive:

[image]

That's from the [*RCA Tunnel Diode Manual*](https://www.yumpu.com/en/document/read/23901571/rca-tunnel-diode-manual) that I linked to in my answer to one of your earlier questions about tunnel diodes.

The solid curve is from a normal diode.  A Zener diode breakdown would be similar.

The tunnel diode hits breakdown at a positive voltage - tunnel diodes conduct in reverse mode, always.

Comment: Surely when under positive bias that's the normal diode conduction. The reverse conduction is Tunnel breakdown which occurs much lower than Zener breakdown.

Comment: @KevinWhite Yes, you are correct. In increasing forward bias a tunnel diode has tunneling current, then that current is suppressed when the bandgap overlap closes, then regular forward conduction takes over at higher bias.

Comment: @Matt - I don't understand your statement "breakdown voltage is positive". In the curve shown the implication is that positive is to the right. Also, you are showing the curve for a backward diode, not a normal tunnel diode.

Comment: @KevinWhite I am doing none of those things, this is not my answer. However I disagree on one point, this is the IV of a tunnel diode. Where do you take exception? Backward diodes and tunnel diodes are very similar, and this exhibits the characteristic negative resistance region of a tunnel diode.

Comment: @Matt. I'm sorry. For some reason, I thought you were the poster.